# Duplicate values with Polymer template repeat

Tags: templates, polymer, repeat, web-component

Okay any I have a strange thing happening with my polymer template

```html
<polymer-element name="my-playlist" attributes="info">
    <template>
        <core-ajax url="/getlist" method="POST" auto response="{{data}}" handleAs="json">
        </core-ajax>
        
        <style>
        </style>
        <core-selector class="list">
            <template repeat="{{k in data}}">
                <core-ajax url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{{k.track}}.json?client_id=9a6dccd301f1d1cbab751e0a1ec82e2e" method="GET" auto response="{{response}}" handleAs="json">
                </core-ajax>
                <div class="item">
                    {{response.genre}}
                </div>
            </template>
        </core-selector>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

What I am getting from this is a repeat of one of the responses that I get.  I get three entries which is correct but the `{{response.genre}}` is repeating one of the responses from the ajax call instead of properly listing each response.  My result looks like:

- R&B
- R&B
- R&B

and it should be something like:

- Rap
- R&B
- Jazz

It seems that I am making all of the proper requests but the template is  - how do I properly handle each response so i am listing all responses instead of duplicating one value?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you using Polymer 0.5 or 1.0 since your code looks like 0.5 code? 1.0 https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat

Comment: 0.5.  Should I upgrade to achieve this functionality?

Comment: No need to upgrade just yet, just wanted to know what code should be used to answer this.

Comment: I think this is happening because response is treated as a global variable, so can you try something for me? Change the for loop to be {k, i in data} where i is the index. Then change the ajax repsonse to write to an array "response='{{response.i}}"'. Last, change response.genre to response.i.genre. Tell me if that works.

Comment: I am getting a blank value - when i just use `{{i}}` I am returned the correct index but `{{response.i}}` does not return anything as well as `{{response.i.genre}}` being blank.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask you to test (got rid of my Polymer 0.5 stuff). Would it be okay to bind to k in data itself? So "response='{{k.response}}"'. I don't know if this will work either, but if worse comes to worse, giving k.response some filler value before hand should give Polymer something to bind to.

Comment: That was it!  now `{{k.response.genre}}` returns the correct values.  This is great, thanks.  This is my second day working with Polymer so this is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that response is being treated as a global variable, so every time you're running through repeat, it is writing over it. As a solution, you should bind to something that would change each repeat.

```html
<template repeat="{{k in data}}">
    <core-ajax url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{{k.track}}.json?client_id=9a6dccd301f1d1cbab751e0a1ec82e2e" method="GET" auto response="{{k.response}}" handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
    <div class="item">
      {{k.response.genre}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: My template looks like this`<template repeat="{{k, i in data}}"></template>`  Edit this and I will accept the answer for sure.

Comment: @MonsterWimp757 Done, but what did you use the index for?

Comment: I take back my last, haha, I do not need the index, your original was correct.

Comment: Okay, removed my index xD